# Does raising magic due to essence loss require Initiation?

Tags: magic, shadowrun-sr5, character-advancement

Playing a mage in Shadowrun who was created with a Synaptic Booster, which lowers essence (and therefore MAG). He was also created with an exceptional attribute of MAG too, so the MAG attribute currently reads *7 (6)*.

My question is, since he technically already had the potential for MAG 7, can I just spend Karma to raise this back, or do I need to Initiate first and always be one behind the max rating?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For every point (or fraction thereof) of Essence lost, both your
>   current Magic Attribute and your maximum Magic Rating are reduced by
>   one. - **SR5, p 278**

If a character loses Essence, it loses both **current** and **maximum** Magic rating. If it was one point below its maximum before installing an implant, it is *still* one point below it afterwards. You can buy that one point, but the maximum is lower, too.

If the character was already *at* maximum, it is *still* at maximum, and that maximum is now lower.

---

As an aside, your nomenclature is unclear. If you're trying to say his Magic is 7, modified to 6, that is not correct. It is 6 - the lost Magic point is **gone**.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared up a lot.

I agree the nomenclature of _7 (6)_ is unclear,  but that's what the GM gave us (generated with Chummer 5 I think).